# DC current through capacitor in Falstad

Tags: simulation, falstad

I am using the Falstad simulator.

I do not understand why am I getting a DC current through a capacitor in simulation.

[image]

This must be an error from the simulator. Please, let me know if I am sane, I don't get why there is current flowing.

Comment: wild guess: what's your time scale? Are you **sure** this is actually a constant current? (Hint: if I ask that way....) this really feels like you want to revisit how current through a capacitor depends on the time-dependent voltage.

Comment: Try to put a small resistance (0.1R) in series with the capacitor. And restart the simulation.

Comment: I'm suprised this works at all - Falstad won't let you connect a direct-cap loop like that. You can post the sim by using "export as link" then pasting the long URL as a link reference. Then we can have a go and see what it's doing.

Comment: Nothing beats letting out the magic smoke for real. Because you rely on creating things from formulas, than guess the part and simulate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you found a convergence corner case.

- Cap directly connected to voltage source: Falstad detects the cap loop and says no.
- Cap connected via ground: Falstad doesn't detect the loop, oscillates (what you're seeing.)
- Cap connected via resistor to ground: Varies. Below 100 mohm, won't settle down. Above 100 mohm, converges.

Here's my sim ([clicky here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgBnETFEPK7ITx8qokADMAhgBsODNgGNacEcqphivUbHhgkSFpDYA3bhl4bePVWJpUkYmAjbYMAoartV%204KFDYA5mYWmsHc%20H5GQV7goTFowqJsAE5qILg0aYKJUNDs0SrZWXiZSUHWRRUlkS5u6R4oCIRpjc0QSaYVDebcTZHK1I7QzkrxfTEZkTpwetSGnGGt9cJLYlKy8gD2vu3KpMjIKNCl3L7YLsK7MPAzubqQEADCkgAOkgoAlgAukgB2CvJsMJmmIwCoAEoMDgfDg-f7yIA)):

[image]

Point being, avoid direct capacitor (and inductor) loops to fixed sources. These always cause trouble with SPICE and its derivatives.

Comment: Convergence is hard. Since it's been distilled into a simple test case, the OP may want to report this bug to Falstad so they get a chance to fix it. For the [CircuitLab circuit simulator](https://www.circuitlab.com/) we've been able to permanently fix many convergence issues from user bug reports over the years. Most recently 3 weeks ago thanks to an [EE.SE question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/552716).